# Magento 2 display old price AND special price in category list

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, special-price

In my old 1.7.0.2 version, I have in a category product list :

"special_price" instead of <del>"regular_price"</del> like : **200$ instead of <del>350$</del>**

As I understand Magento2 change the way of setting special_price for a configurable product, but also the way of this special_price is display (seems to display the lowest price for simple products associated)

How Can I display the old price **AND** the special_price in Magento2 ?

PS : I use only configurable products

Comment: There is however another issue with this solution - if you change swatch on configurable product to a swatch that has no discount applied (therefore old price hides), old price hides on all other configurable products on listing as well. This is because configurable-product/../configurable.js the only selector is the "sly-old-price" but with no scope of which product container swatch is changed. Any ideas how to modify this?

Comment: sorry I use swatch only for size and discount in my case are the same whatever the size (like in Magento1).

Answer (score 17):

Found solution here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7624

Copy `final_price.phtml` from

**Vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

to

**Vendor/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

change (around line 22)

`<?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>`
with
`<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>`

(special_price will display)

and replace
`<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">`
by
`<span class="old-price sly-old-price">`

(remove the **no-display** class)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, after update the final_price.phtml, there's still an inline css gengerated as "display:none". Not sure why is that happening, I had to use css rewrite to get it work.

Comment: I also removed 'sly-old-price' class to fix `display:none` inline css that was hiding ol price.

Comment: @RehanMobin Your comment has to be a part of the solution by default!

Comment: @araujophillips I can edit the post if you want but in my case it works without removing this class. Probably something in the theme I bought... I will try with luma in a blank M2 and sample data to see