# Magento 2 configurable products sale old price not showing

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, labels, sale-price

I've `Magento V.2.2.2` running well, except for the configurable product listing dose not show any information about `Sale`,

- no old price showing next to the new special price
- no sale label is showing on on-sale configurable product

Please any way to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Did you find out why?

Comment: Try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196090/magento-2-display-old-price-and-special-price-in-category-list